# React - extend events to include children

Tags: reactjs, jsx, parent, children

I'm very new to react and I'm having trouble extending an mouse leave event to a rendered sub-menu.

currently the mouse hovers over navbar item and sub-menu renders. mouse leaves navigation bar item to select item from submenu. submenu disappears. I would like the submenu to stay open while the mouse is over the nav item AND within the sub-menu. I've tried multiple different things at this point, but I'm struggling to understand how to make some conditional logic that will work.

Here is the function that renders the child.

```
function NavItem(props) {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false)
  return (
    <li className='nav-item'>
      <p1 className='icon-button' onMouseEnter={() => setOpen(!open)} onMouseLeave={() => setOpen(false)}>
        {props.name}
      </p1>
      {open && props.children}    
    </li> 
  )
}
```

this is the child function.

```
function PlatformMenu() {
  return (
    <div className='dropdown' >
      <li>
        <ul className='dropdown-item' ><a href='#'>Sub-Menu Item</a></ul>
      </li>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Maybe a bit of a typical stack answer, but I would not recommend using a hover action to open/close a dropdown menu. Using `onClick` to set a class and some basic CSS to ether show or hide the submenu is way more reliable. This is especailly relevant for mobile devices where hover is not a thing.

Comment: Thank you for the advice, I will definitely do that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put submenu inside your p1, like this for example:

```
 <li className='nav-item'>
      <p1 className='icon-button' onMouseEnter={() => setOpen(!open)} 
           onMouseLeave={() => setOpen(false)}>
        {props.name}
        {open && props.children}    
      </p1>
    </li>
```

***p.s.:***
I will join the answer in the comments, I would not advise you to use the state for this task, it is better to use CSS styles for this.

Comment: Man, I can't believe I didn't try this before... Thank you very much. I'll heed the advice as well.